# how to scrape part of the file name of a folder of csvs and insert that name as a column into the data frame in R

Tags: r, read.csv

I have a folder of 30 csvs with names such as data-0601-0909 -daily_2018-06-24.csv but these csvs do not have Date column.

I would like to have write a loop and substr the last part of the name'2018-06-24' as a date column to the file. Each file will only has a date column with the same date.

I tried to use the code following to read large amount csvs all in once as one dataframe but stuck in assigning a new column by the file name.

```
 files = list.files(pattern="*.csv") 
 myfiles = do.call(rbind, lapply(files, function(x) read.csv(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

using purr, readr, and stringr, and dplyr, you can do the following

```
library(purrr)
library(readr)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$")

map_dfr(files, function(filename) {
    read_csv(filename) %>%
      mutate(date = str_extract(filename, "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}(?=\\.csv$)"))
})
```

For the regex, see: https://regex101.com/r/bJOmzn/1

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I tried the code and it returned error: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: argument "pattern" is missing, with no default.

Comment: I forgot the filename in str_extract. Now it should work

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not entirely sure exactly what data is contained within your data frames; but we can use lapply and a custom function to assign each row a date (taken from file name) and then rbind these together.

Step 1: Get files from working directory

```
files <- list.files(pattern = '\\.csv')
```

Step 2: Custom function that first reads a csv file, then strips the final elements from the filename, then adds this as a further column

```
files_with_date <- function(filename){
  a <- read.csv(filename, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  b <- substr(filename,(nchar(filename)+1)-14, nchar(filename)-4)
  cbind(a,b) 
}
```

Step 3: Wrap this in a do.call to rbind, and within this, lapply the function to our list

```
myfiles <- do.call(rbind, lapply(files, files_with_date))
```

The substr function is slightly hacky....